# Operation result with one of the variables null (empty) in SAS

Tags: sas

I am converting SAS code to C# code and I don't have platform to run SAS code, what I have only source code, and I have line of the code in SAS where one of the variables is empty and another is not and I would like to know what would be result of y in following operation.

```
x = .
y = x - 1;
```

x is empty (null) Please advice.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.